# Is it possible to change key bindings in Sublime Text dynamically from a plugin?

Tags: key-bindings, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to change key bindings in Sublime Text dynamically from a plugin or from the console, like in Vim?

A related question: is it possible to choose a keymap file based on the current keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's possible, but in a non-standard manner. You will have to create a custom `.sublime-keymap` file that your package will manage completely by it's own by writing/reading to/from it.

On your second question: no, it's not possible to even get what type of layout is currently active.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does it mean that there is nothing like Vim's `map` command?  Is it possible to at least inspect the current key bindings other than by reading the keymap file?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. There's almost nothing in ST API that works with keybindings. Sometimes it feels strange, that such powerful editor with good API can't do basic stuff like this.